# C# - Unhandled Exception - Illegal Characters in Path

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am just testing some code at the moment, although when calling the StartRemoveDuplicate (when its compiled) an Exception is thrown, complaining about illegal characters:

[image: error]

My code is as follows:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (string exename in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"))
            {
                Process.Start("test.exe", "\"" + exename + "\"").WaitForExit();
            }

            StartRemoveDuplicate();

        }



        private static void RemoveDuplicate(string sourceFilePath, string destinationFilePath)
        {
            var readLines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFilePath, Encoding.Default);

            File.WriteAllLines(destinationFilePath, readLines.Distinct().ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
        }


        private static void StartRemoveDuplicate()
        {
            RemoveDuplicate("C:\test.txt", "C:\test2.txt");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use @ before the string like :

```
@"C:\test.txt"
```

or to escpe the "\" caracter

```
"C:\\test.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

Backslash is considered a special character in C# strings, usually used to escape other characters.  So you can tell it to treat backslashes as normal by prefixing your literals with `@` before the quotes:

```
RemoveDuplicate(@"C:\test.txt", @"C:\test2.txt");
```

Or, you can escape it with double backslashes:

```
RemoveDuplicate("C:\\test.txt", "C:\\test2.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

the \t in C:\test is probably being seen as a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Use Path.Combine to combine parts of file paths. It handles the details of "\" characters.