# Question Mark in Querystring with Server.MapPath returning an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, query-string, server.mappath

I am working on a web application. Here I am storing attachments/uploads on server physical directory. The parent folder of uploads may contain special characters like '?'

Example of URL

```
"~/ChapterFiles/Capgeminisdfsdf_BE CSE ?_CoverPic/CoverPic.jpg"
```

When I am doing, `Server.MapPath()` on this URL, I am getting an error `"Illegal characters in path."`

Can't remove question mark from folder name as it's part of requirement. Please suggest a solution, I need to fix it urgently.

Comment: do you want to replace that ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146134/how-to-remove-illegal-characters-from-path-and-filenames

Comment: I want to handle the question mark in query string. Can't replace, then it would not map with physical location on server

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
String absoluteDir = Server.MapPath("~");
String myRelativePath = "~/ChapterFiles/Capgeminisdfsdf_BE CSE ?  _CoverPic/CoverPic.jpg".Replace("/","\\");

String absolutePath = Path.Combine(absoluteDir,myRelativePath);
```

It will work. I advice you to write some unit tests for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` and `UrlDecode` to encode/decode the string.

Answer (score 0):

[Question marks are not allowed in folder names in Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#naming_conventions). Your requirement in it's current form is impossible to implement and there is no "fix". You need to rethink how to map URL's to folder and file names.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `@` sign before the string. Like below

```
@"~/ChapterFiles/Capgeminisdfsdf_BE CSE ?_CoverPic/CoverPic.jpg"
```

[Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388531/c-sharp-unhandled-exception-illegal-characters-in-path)